# Mailcore2 - search emails starting from specific date

Tags: ios, mailcore, mailcore2

Not sure is there anybody here with mailcore2 iOS IMAP framework experience.
But what I need is to retrieve all(or some of them) emails, which has send day after than a specific date.

Does mailcore2 provides this feature? I know that IMAP has this and guess mailcore2 will have it as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For now, this feature is not available on mailcore2.
Though, it could be added: It's available at libetpan level.
Could you file a feature request on github issues so I can make progress on it?
A pull request would also be welcome.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Dinh, will do!